# Tracking down compiler errors thrown outside my code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

VS compiler failed to compile some of my code. However, the error that appeared was not located in my own code, but in one of the core classes (e.g. vector, utility, etc).

Is there any way to see which line of MY code caused (called the method/constructor/something else that failed) the compilation error in the core class?

Something similar to "up one level" button when stepping through the code once it does compile.

EDIT: Similar question was put on hold, this is this question reworded and clarified.

Comment: If you look at the output of the compiler, rather than the 'error list' you'll see the full details of the error, including where in your code you were using the template

Comment: When you use templates and there are errors, there's usually a "used from..." line (or similar) that show where in your code the error originates from. You really need to read *all* of the message, not just gloss over it. If you edit your question to include the full, complete and unmodified error output (*as text*, copy-pasted) then we might help you find it.

Comment: can you show the error message? We can probably help you parse it to figure it out.

Comment: I was asking generally, for any error which happens outside the code. But, from what I can tell, this will always be related to templates, right?
And with the used from... I should always be able to locate it.

Comment: It depends a little bit on the errors. Template errors most of the time have some way to get back to the originating point in your code but there are also other errors that could be reported in unrelated (or even system) header files. For such errors it help to go back the include chain (which might be reported through "included from..." or similar) and look at the code before the top-most inclusion. It might be a missing semicolon, or unterminated string or block. And it could be in a previously included header file.